# how to hook into fetch method not using service worker?

Tags: javascript, fetch

how to hook into fetch method not using service worker ?

I know i can use service worker to do it, but is there other way ? not using service worker ?

**Important**:

1. I would like to do some stuff before i actually fetch resource from
   server like **fetch response from other sources instead**
2. If I am using some vendor module that is using `fetch`, I'd like to override that one as well

## service worker way

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Let the browser do its default thing
  // for non-GET requests.
  if (event.request.method != 'GET') return;

  // Prevent the default, and handle the request ourselves.
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Try to get the response from a cache.
    const cache = await caches.open('dynamic-v1');
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);

    if (cachedResponse) {
      // If we found a match in the cache, return it, but also
      // update the entry in the cache in the background.
      event.waitUntil(cache.add(event.request));
      return cachedResponse;
    }

    // If we didn't find a match in the cache, use the network.
    return fetch(event.request);
  }());
});
```

## non service worker way

The one thing that comes to my mind is to wrap `window.fetch` method but i do no like this solution.

```
window.fetch = async function(requestUrl) {
  // Try to get the response from a cache.
  const cache = await caches.open('dynamic-v1');
  const url = new URL(requestUrl);
  const cachedResponse = await cache.match(url.pathname);

  if (cachedResponse) {
    return cachedResponse;
  }

  return fetch(requestUrl);
}
```

Ofc this examples are just theoretical, so any ideas ?

Comment: Create a new function `myFetch` and call that instead of `fetch`.

Comment: this is what I do not want to do, what if I am using some vendor module that is using `fetch` ? I'd like to override that one as well

Comment: You should include any and all requirements for a solution in the question if you expect people to know what they are.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real answer to this question but anyway I am going to post this here as maybe it will help someone.

So what I rly needed to do is to handle some stuff on the client side (not in the sw) and I achieved it by using `MessageChannel` letting sw and client communicate both ways.

## what I did:

1. set sw to listen on fetch event
2. create MessageChannel in a promise letting client send a response
3. send a fetch event to a client with MessageChannel
4. client - do stuff
5. send response back to sw witch MessageChannel

U can get the basic idea from this google example:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/

the most important part is to delegate work to client letting it to response on the other port, turning the whole process in a promise like this:

```
// This wraps the message posting/response in a promise, which will resolve if the response doesn't
// contain an error, and reject with the error if it does. If you'd prefer, it's possible to call
// controller.postMessage() and set up the onmessage handler independently of a promise, but this is
// a convenient wrapper.
return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
  messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function (event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.error) {
      reject(event.data.error);
    } else {
      resolve(event.data);
    }
  };

  // This sends the message data as well as transferring messageChannel.port2 to the client.
  // The client can then use the transferred port to reply via postMessage(), which
  // will in turn trigger the onmessage handler on messageChannel.port1.
  // See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dom-worker-postmessage
  client.postMessage(message, [messageChannel.port2]);

  // Set up the timeout
  setTimeout(() => {
    messageChannel.port1.close();
    messageChannel.port2.close();

    reject('Promise timed out after ' + this.timeoutAfter + ' ms');

  }, this.timeoutAfter);
});
```

If u'd like to see my use case it is available [here](https://github.com/vardius/peer-cdn/blob/master/src/plugins/Delegate.js) where the work is done by [MessageClient](https://github.com/vardius/peer-cdn/blob/master/src/clients/MessageClient.js)

feel free to ask question, will be happy to answer